Commutativity of the wreath product
Let $G$ be a subgroup of the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_n$ and $H$ be a subgroup of $\mathfrak{S}_m$. Recall that the wreath product $G \wr H$ is the semi-direct product $G^m \rtimes H$, where $H$ acts on the direct product $G^m$ by permuting components. We can also consider $H \wr G$, the semi-direct product $H^n \rtimes G$.
My question is : when are $G \wr H$ and $H \wr G$ isomorphic? My suspicion is that it is only the case when $m = n$ and $G \cong H$, or when $G$ and $H$ are both the trivial group. But I can't come up with a proof, nor with a counterexample.
Attempt : First, if $|G|^m|H| \neq |H|^n|G|$, it is obvious, because it is the cardinality of each group. Suppose it is equal, and that there exists an isomorphism $f : G \wr H \to H \wr G$. I suspect that if $f$ is injective for both $G$ and $H$ (considered as subgroups of $G \wr H$), then $|H \wr G|$ must be much bigger than $|G \wr H|$, which is a contradiction. But i don't know if this intuition is good, nor how to formalize it.

Your condition $m=n$ and $G \cong H$ is not sufficient for $G \wr H \cong H \wr G$. I can think of a counterexample with $G \cong H \cong S_5$ and $m=n=10$, using different subgroups of order $12$ as point stabilizers in $G$ and $H$.

In fact there are smaller examples with intransitive $H$ and $G$. Let $G$ and $H$ be the subgroups $\langle(1,2)\rangle$ and $\langle(1,2)(3,4)\rangle$ of $S_4$. Then $G \wr H \not\cong H \wr G$. The condition for commutativity might be that $G$ and $H$ are conjugate subgroups of $S_n$, but it might be difficult to prove it.

Maybe a more tractable condition would be $G\wr H$ and $H\wr G$ being conjugate subgroups of $S_{mn}$.

Cross-posted at MOF (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/473002/commutativity-of-the-wreath-product), where isomorphisms are replaced by conjugates, to the comments’ suggestion.
